# Index.php using 100% CPU

Tags: plugins, ssh

I am using godaddy 32 gb(RAM), quad core(CPU) dedicated server.

My site is working properly till today somehow its take to long to load so i am monitoring server in SSH using top command and i had found that my wordpress `index.php` is continuously requesting.

I can see that there are 8-10 request of `index.php` which are in running stat every request runs till 3-4 second and after that a new request is come.

I had not added any additional htaccess code.

I had deactivated all the plugins but its doesn't work.

I am very afraid, is this any attack from bots or something?
How to solve this kind of problem?

Please let me know if anyone have idea about it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should check if your hosting company can help. The access/error logs can sometimes help.

Comment: Sounds like poorly written code. Check plugins & theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise specified (usually happens on admin side, and image access), all requests to wordpress pass and are processed by the `index.php` file, therefor it is not very interesting to look at which file is being "run", you should look more at the request log and how much time it takes to complete each request.

So if it is not any kind of attack, you probably have a traffic spike which might be worth investigating it source, but whether it is a DDOS attempt or just normal traffic, it sounds like either your theme code can be optimized or there is some thing that can be improved in your server setup.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help.

I found an issue and solution.

This caused by the fake bot which named as **"baidu search engine's crawler"**, its continuously send a request to our server.

So, i had deny all the request from that fake bot's IP range using below code in `.htaccess` file:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from 180.76.15.0/24
Allow from all
```

So now my server is stable.
Thanks for the help again.